# Sending data with ESP32 to Firebase Error- Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp32

I am working on a program that uses a scanner to save a barcode in a firebase realtime database. The scanner works, and I have already established a connection with the firebase. But now I can't send a barcode to the database (Error reason: Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.).

Here is the code:

```
void loop(){

if (scannerSerial.available() > 0) { 

String barcodeData = scannerSerial.readStringUntil('\n');

Serial.println(barcodeData); 

Serial.println("Barcode: " + barcodeData);

if (Firebase.ready() && signupOK && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > 15000 || sendDataPrevMillis == 0)){
  sendDataPrevMillis = millis();
  
  // Write on the database path test/int
  if (Firebase.RTDB.setString(&fbdo, "test/int", barcodeData)){
    Serial.println("PASSED");
    Serial.println("PATH: " + fbdo.dataPath());
    Serial.println("TYPE: " + fbdo.dataType());
    Serial.println("Barcode: " + barcodeData);
    digitalWrite(ledPinGreen, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledPinGreen, LOW);
  }
    else {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + fbdo.errorReason());
      digitalWrite(ledPinRed, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(ledPinRed, LOW);
    }
    
}
} }
```

As a test I changed the `String barcodeData = "Hello";` which is working. So i can be sure that the connection to the firebase is working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you checked if `barcodeData` ends with a pesky `\r` character?

Comment: @samthecodingman Thank you for drawing my attention to this!

Comment: @hcheung The Firebase client library for the ESP32 uses `Firebase.RTDB.setString` to serialize the provided string as JSON before sending it off to the RTDB.

Comment: @user21007637 Was that the `\r` character the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I changed `('\n')` to `('\r')` and now it works (carriage return character).